# What program can I use to paste a new face over another person?

Tags: software-rec, photos, editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good and free image editor? (Alternative to Photoshop)](https://superuser.com/questions/25451/what-is-a-good-and-free-image-editor-alternative-to-photoshop)

I'm trying to paste the picture of a face over another person's face with a free program (i.e. not Photoshop).

It doesn't have to look pretty — I just cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

[Paint.Net](http://www.getpaint.net/) is your free choice.